# Spark on Yarn with Jdk8

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, java-8, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark job on hadoop yarn (hadoop 2.7.0 but also tried 2.4.0, all on my box using the downloads from apache-hadoop web site and spark 1.3.1). My spark job is in scala but contains classes compiled with jdk8.

When I run hadoop on jdk8, I get

```
INFO yarn.Client: 
 client token: N/A
 diagnostics: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.
 ApplicationMaster host: kostas-pc
 ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
 queue: default
 start time: 1431513335001
 final status: SUCCEEDED
```

Even if the job is marked as SUCCEEDED, it actually didn't do anything due to "Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.". In fact no logging is visible from my spark job.

When I switch the jdk that I run hadoop, to jdk7, my job starts running and I can see log entries from my scala code, but when it gets to the code compiled with jdk8 it fails with incompatible class error (as expected).

So it seems running hadoop+spark with jdk8 is not compatible. Are there any solutions to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems spark 1.4.0 is ok with jdk8